# invalid method declaration, return type required, on a GUI

Tags: java, swing, return

So im trying to make a simple GUI that goes up by one when you click a button in it. I get this error, however, when i try and run the test GUI: [Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo35H.png) Here is the code

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main {

public GUI() {

  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.setBorder(borderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
  panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

  frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setTitle("Clicks");
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);

}

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    new GUI();

  }
}
```

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: Line 8 has the error I linked an image if you wanna see the full thing

Comment: put ```public void GUI()``` in method.That should solve the issue

Comment: Please don't link to images, just cut and paste the error into your question.  Also indicate which line is "8", we don't necessarily see the same code as you (because SO might reformat your code differently).

Comment: Your error states that return type is missing in method declaration. Return type is mandatory for  Method .If you are not returning anyhting , use ```void``` type . If you don't want to specify any return type , use a constructor instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

public GUI() {
```

`GUI` seems intended as a constructor and the constructor must have the same name as the class. But neither `GUI` nor `Main` are good, descriptive names for a class / constructor. The name should be descriptive of that the class actually is. So here is something that might not only be better, but *should* work for this case.

```
public class ClicksGUI {

public ClicksGUI() {
```

Note that if changing the name of the class / constructor, the reference in the `main` method also needs to change to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `GUI` to be a function you must specify a `return type` (I suppose you want `void` in your case),  and call it like a regular function, not to create an object of it:

```
public class Main {

public static void GUI() {

  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.setBorder(borderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
  panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

  frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setTitle("Clicks");
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);

}

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    GUI();

  }
}
```

Comment: but ```GUI()``` is a method in ```Main``` class.Won't making GUI as class return type throw error . ?

Comment: if `GUI` is a method what are you trying to do with `new GUI();`

Answer (score 0):

Add `void` as return type for your GUI method

```
public class Main {

public static void GUI() {
.....
}
}
```

and call it as a method from main() method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GUI();

  }
```

Java expects a return type for methods . If you don't want to specify return type , use a constructor instead.